# How do I reassemble this Quando rear hub?

Tags: hub, axle

Closely related to [how to reassemble mountain bike rear wheel hub and bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/how-to-reassemble-mountain-bike-rear-wheel-hub-and-bearings?newreg=ba4f7f1162be4695b4b609bfeacb64db), but not quite identical and my noob brain cannot piece things back together.

I disassembled the rear hub to clean it and remove rust, and of course thought too highly of myself to take any picture of how it used to fit together.

[image]

Here's what I (think) I managed to identify:

A: Nuts for fitting to the frame

B-C: Nuts and spacers to hold the cones together?

D: Cones, of two different thicknesses - not sure which one goes on which side?

E: Rubber seal? no idea where it goes

F: Metal seal, I understood it needs to go on one on the cones, but on which side?

G: Very thin and very (!) worn out spacer. No idea where it was

H: Very long spacer, same material as the cones

I: Extremely worn out axle. Any idea where I can buy one? Does it have to be exactly the same model?

I would very much appreciate any help :-)

---

EDIT: I finally found the original part (https://www.ktgroup.net/pro.php?m=d&pid=113&cid=47&f=1). It seems like some of the components I have aren't original (it's a second hand bike so who knows what happened before I got it). Also there is absolutely no way I can find to order a replacement part here in Europe. Can I put another axle? Also it seems like I am missing one of the metal seals. Are those standard ?

Comment: The assemblies in the picture you linked do not look the same as the parts in your picture. The right hand linked picture would be the rear and it has three of your "B" type nuts and a small and large spacer, not just one "H" like your picture. That being said the linked picture provides some clues.

Comment: Cellphone cameras are a gloriously handy thing while taking something apart.  Sequential photos of disassembly help a lot... but you're a bit past that stage now sorry.

Comment: Yes. Every time I swear to myself to take more pictures next time. I never do.

Answer (score 4):

How good does this have to be?
If you are going to use this as daily transportation to work I'd want the correct dust seals and I'd go with a different wheel.
If this is a klunker you don't really care about I think you can experiment and arrive at a workable assembly.

Here's my best guess at something workable.
Parts "F" and "E" look like dust guards. Sometimes they press fit into the hub AFTER the bearings are greased into the races.Sometimes, like in the picture you linked, they are attached to the cone. They usually match so I'm not sure what to make of the rubber seal. See if it will press into the hub on one side or the other.

With the bearings in and the dust covers on (assuming they fit into the hub)
And, with the freewheel off - if possible.

1. Thread the thin cone "D" about 1.5 inches down the axle.
2. Thread locknut "B" after the cone until it hits the cone
3. Tighten the locknut against the cone but only snug - not tight, you'll probably have to move it later.
4. Insert your axle assembly into the non-freewheel side
5. Thread the fat cone onto the freewheel side of the assembly until it just touches the bearings.
6. Slide the spacer "H" onto the freewheel side
7. Thread the other locknut "B" onto the freewheel side
8. Play with the left over washer "G" and see which side it works on. My guess is that it will go on the freewheel side. I'd put it between a lock nut and the spacer if it helps spacing on the freewheel side. If it helps the spacing on the non-freewheel side I'd put it between the cone and the lock nut.

Now you play with the spacing so that the wheel is spaced in the frame, the freewheel spins and the chain has enough room on the smallest freewheel gear to clear the frame and the axle sticks out about the same amount on each side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. It's a cassette, not freewheel, and I think the rubber seal is meant to go on the side of the cassette as a metal seal wouldn't fit there. I managed to mount something that looks reasonable thanks to your instructions, I'll do some maintenance on the chain now then try to put it back. Do you maybe know from experience if I can use any other axle of the same diameter? (mine is bent and worn out). Also, what about the "C" spacers? Do these go between "A" and the frame?

Comment: Any other axle that the nuts will thread onto smoothly and is at least as long should work.

Comment: My guess is it is a 10mm diameter x 1mm thread pitch axle. There are also 10mmx26tpi axles out there. The nut would start to thread for a few turns then get really tight. Best to verify at a shop if you can.